# How can I 'break out' of a while loop but still do the while loop?

Tags: java

I would like to have a while loop that if a certain condition is true, do not do the code below it and then continue with the while loop.
Here is some psuedocode:

```
boolean poop
while (poop){
    if (player.isAwesome()){
        Continue doing while loop but do not execute below code
    }
    poop = false;
}
```

Yes, I can use something like this:

```
boolean poop
while (poop){
    boolean stopPoop = false;
    if (player.isAwesome()){
        stopPoop = true;
    }
    if (!stopPoop){
        poop = false;
    }
}
```

However, that is sort of messy and inconvenient, and I was wondering if there is a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
boolean poop = true;
while (poop){
    if (player.isAwesome()){
        //Continue doing while loop but do not execute below code
        continue;
    }
    poop = false;
}
```

Yes, that's right use the `continue` keyword.  If you wanted to break out of the loop you could use the `break` keyword

If you have nest loops then you can also continue to a label.

Comment: Thanks! That works.

Apparently I can "You can accept an answer in 5 minutes", so I will accept it then.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the need for the poop variable.
can't you just use this.

```
while (player.isAwesome()){

    Continue doing while loop but do not execute below code
}
```

Comment: In my real code that is exactly what I do, however I thought it would be easier to do psuedocode with an example boolean already there.

My real code is ' while (stop == 1 || stop == -1)'.

Just for the record, 1 is if the person clicks "Cancel", the other one is if they click "Close".

Answer (score 4):

In cases such as these where it is difficult to predict when a loop should be terminated, I prefer to use

```
do {
    if (player.isAwesome()){
        //Continue doing while loop but do not execute below code
        continue;
    }
    // This code will only execute once
} while (false);
```

This removes the need for the boolean flag which pollutes the scope outside the loop.

I discourage `for (;;)` or `while (true)` since, over time, maintenance of code written in this way *can* introduce infinite looping.

Comment: Very interesting. I will certainly keep this in mind!

Comment: Interesting construct.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using java for coding.
All you need to do is write

```
continue;
```

at the line you need to go to the while loop check statement. So:

```
boolean poop
while (poop){
    if (player.isAwesome()){
        continue;
    }
    poop = false;
}
```